# $location.path(path) with ngNewRouter Angularjs 1.4.4 is not working consistently

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I have started using "`ngNewRouter`". In my application, using javascript I need to switch between multiple component. I have used  `$location.path(path);` however it is not working consistent. Following are details.

//Define routes

```
    $router.config([
            {path: "/", redirectTo: "userauthentication"}, // The default URL is redirected to userauthentication component.
            {path: "/userauthentication", component: "userauthentication"},
            {path: "/adminview", component: "adminview"},
            {path: "/clubonboarding/:clubid", component: "clubonboarding"},
            {path: "/membermanagement", component: "membermanagement"}
        ]);

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Code which are working:

```
$location.path("adminview");
```

Code which is not working:

```
$location.path("userauthentication");
```

Its surprise me as it works at few place and doesn't work for others. Am I missing anything here.

Please advice.

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Do you get an error? Do you get the wrong page? Does the event to trigger this code never fire? It's not clear at all what the problem is here.

Comment: Yes, event gets triggered, but view doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Your path is relative an not absolute.

If you are at view `/clubonboarding/:clubid` and you wanna go to `userauthentication` the router will resolve the relativ path to `/clubonboarding/userauthentication`.

Comment: I tried with "/userauthentication" but its not working, I see URL changes to "/userauthentication" and very quickly come back to "/clubonboarding/:clubid"

Comment: Then check the network protocol. is it trying to load the `userauthentication` template? Are there any errors? Do all resources return the correct content? as you use `html5Mode` it might be it will return the default `index.html` instead.

Comment: i have added code to redirect /userauthentication on page refresh in /clubonboarding/:clubid view. On page refresh it loads index.html and for a moment it changes URL to /userauthentication and come back to /clubonboarding/:clubid. I checked network call and its not loading template for "userauthentication". I am sure i am missing something...but not sure what.